# jQuery post with ajax from variable number of input boxes

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass user input for a variable number of inputs for two different fields back to the controller using jQuery post with ajax. I am having trouble getting more than just the first inputs. For example, if an employee is assigned multiple pieces of equipment, only the first one is passed to the controller.

In the View I am displaying each employee in a table with a button for each to open a modal where their individual equipment can be assigned. In each modal there are two text boxes (vehicles & tools) with the option for the user to add more of each using jQuery.

I am new to JS, and can't figure out how to determine how many inputs there are, and I don't know how to put these into an array to pass to the controller. Any help is very appreciated!

**View:**

```
@int count = 0;

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-@count">
                Assign Resources
            </button>

            <div class="modal fade" id="modal-@count" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">@item.Rank @item.FirstName @item.LastName</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <input type="hidden" value="@item.assignedRosterID" id="assignedRosterID-@count" />
                            <div class="table">

                                <table>
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="text-center">
                                                Vehicles
                                            </th>

                                            <th class="text-center">
                                                Equipment
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="middle">
                                                <div class=”addV” id=”addV-@count”>
                                                    <p>
                                                        <input type="text" size="20" class="text-center" value="" id="vehicleNumber-@count" name=”vehicle” placeholder="Vehicle Number" /> &nbsp;
                                                    </p>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>

                                            <td valign="middle">
                                                <div class="addEquip" id="addEquip-@count">
                                                    <p>
                                                        <input type="text" id="equipmentLabel-@count" size="20" class="text-center" name="equipment" value="" placeholder="Equipment Label" />&nbsp;
                                                    </p>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>

                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <a href="#" class="addVehicle" id="addVehicle-@count"> Add Additional Vehicle</a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <a href="#" class="addEquipment" id="addEquipment-@count"> Add Additional Equipment</a>

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <span style="color: red"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="closeModal-@count">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="saveModal-@count">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>


        <td style="font-weight:bold">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td style="font-weight:bold">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        </td>
    </tr>
    count++;
}
```

JS

```
for (var i = 0; i < $('#count').val() ; i++) {
(function (i) {
    i
    $('#saveModal-' + i).click(function () {


        var DetailsVM = {
            arID: $('#assignedRosterID-' + i).val(),
            vehicleNumber: $('#vehicleNumber-' + i).val(),
            equipmentLabel: $('#equipmentLabel-' + i).val()
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Rosters/SaveResources',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(DetailsVM),
            traditional: true,
            success: function (response) {
                alert("Data Inserted Successfully!");
            },
            error: function (xhr, err) { alert(xhr.responseText) }



        });
    });
})(i);
};



for (var i = 0; i < $('#count').val() ; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        $(function () {
            var addDiv = $('#addV-' + i);
            var j = $('#addV-' + i + 'p').size() + 1;


            $(document).on('click', '#addVehicle + i, function () {
                $('<p><input type="text" id="vehicle + i + '-' + j + '" size="20" name="vehicle + j + '" value="" placeholder=" Vehicle Number" /><a href="#" id="remNew"> Remove</a> </p>').appendTo(addDiv);
                j++;

                return false;
            });

            $(document).on('click', '#remNew', function () {
                if (j > 1) {
                    $(this).parents('p').remove();
                    j--;
                    //$("span").text("There are " + j + " equipment input boxes. ");
                }
                return false;
            });
        });

    })(i);
};



for (var i = 0; i < $('#count').val() ; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        $(function () {
            var addDiv = $('#addEquip-' + i);
            var j = $('#addEquip-' + i + 'p').size() + 1;


            $(document).on('click', '#addEquipment-' + i, function () {
                $('<p><input type="text" id="equipment-' + i + '-' + j + '" size="20" name="equipment_' + j + '" value="" placeholder=" Equipment Label " /><a href="#" id="remNew"> Remove</a> </p>').appendTo(addDiv);
                j++;

                return false;
            });

            $(document).on('click', '#remNew', function () {
                if (j > 1) {
                    $(this).parents('p').remove();
                    j--;
                    //$("span").text("There are " + j + " equipment input boxes. ");
                }
                return false;
            });
        });

    })(i);


  };
```

Model:

```
 public class DetailsVM
    {
        public string arID { get; set; }
        public string vehicleNumber { get; set; }
        public string equipmentLabel { get; set; }

}
```

The logic for this is only setup to save one of each type since multiple is not working. When I put a break point on this and inspect VM it only contains the first values.

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult SaveResources(DetailsVM VM)
        {
            int assignedRosterID = Int32.Parse(VM.arID);
            int equipmentID = db.Equipments.Where(x => x.EquipmentLabel == VM.equipmentLabel).Select(x => x.EquipmentID).FirstOrDefault();
            int vehicleID = db.Vehicles.Where(x => x.VehicleNumber == VM.vehicleNumber).Select(x => x.VehicleID).FirstOrDefault();


        var tempEquipments = new TempEquipment();
        tempEquipments.AssignedRosterID = assignedRosterID;
        tempEquipments.EquipmentID = equipmentID;
        db.TempEquipments.Add(tempEquipments);

        var tempVehicles = new TempVehicle();
        tempVehicles.AssignedRosterID = assignedRosterID;
        tempVehicles.VehicleID = vehicleID;
        db.TempVehicles.Add(tempVehicles);


db.SaveChanges();


        return Json(1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Comment: show us the controller action `Rosters/SaveResources`

Comment: are your fields added dynamically? then you have to name your first funtion ... and it must be a global function... and whenever you add a new field ( !! with new save-button you want to trigger an event !! ) you must rerun your function

Comment: @VenkataPanga Edited post to include contoller action. As noted, this logic is only setup for one of each type. Thanks!

Comment: @Mephiztopheles Thanks for the reply! The fields are added dynamically. Could you please give some more detail for your solution? I'm still trying to learn JavaScript.

Comment: poested it as answer

Answer (score 1):

you can set a class on the save-buttons and get the parent tr by
`var tr = $(this).closest('tr')`
 so ... the arID would be like
 `tr.find('[name="arID"]')`
wrap your first `for` in a function and make it global.
to make it globale, decline it above the `for` like

```
function bindClick() {}
```

then you will not need your `for` due to your class on the button.
in your  bindClick you can go

```
$('.saveModal').each(function( ){
    $(this).unbind('click').on('click, function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // do this if you dont want to do default action for this button .. like to submit a form
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr') // get the parent of all inputs to search in this container
        [native code] // var DetailsVM = {...
    }
});
```

then change `$('#assignedRosterID-' + i).val()` to `tr.find('.assignedRosterID').val()`
Don't forget to add classes to the inputs! or find them by attribute name : `tr.find('[name="your-field-name"]').val()`

do the same with your other functions and trigger the `bindClick` in your function, where you add the new fields ;)

Comment: Thanks for the additional details. I couldn't really figure out the different functions and unbind, but I figured out a different solution. I ended up assigning a class to the text boxes (ie - class="vehicleNumber-@count"). Then using a .each loop put these values into an array.